# Problems while installing an application / no module named photologue

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb, photologue

Hey there i got a problem installing photologue application. Im following installation instructions.

```
~/coffee$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Mar 18 2009, 13:52:30) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import photologue
>>> photologue.VERSION
(2, 3)
```

but after adding

```
'photologue',
```

to my installed apps, when i try to python manage.py syncdb im getting an error:

```
Error: No module named photologue,
```

Whats the reason of that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have multiple versions of Python and Django is using a different one from the one photologue was installed to.

Or if you're using virtualenvs, you might have installed photologue into the main Python site-packages, that virtualenvs, typically and intentionally, don't have access to.

Comment: thanks, ill try a find a way to work this out. gonna report afterwardds.

Comment: added :$HOME/coffee to my #PYTHONPATH in .environment   /*installed photologue app inside my project*/ it works, thumbs up! :)